# Initialization statement

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm reading a Java book and I came across an interesting for loop. It looks like this:

```
for(; (j>0) && (tmp < a[j-1]); j--)
```

I understand that `(j>0) && (tmp < a[j-1])` is the condition check and `j--` is the decrease of the variable. However, I don't get where's the initialization statement.

Comment: it's the first after the `for(` in your case, none

Comment: possible duplicate of [for loop without index declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208503/for-loop-without-index-declaration)

Comment: You will probably find this one odd too at some point if you haven't already: `for (;;)`

Comment: `j--` is a decrement, not an increment.

Answer (score 2):

There is no initialization statement in your example. It's optional.

`j` is probably declared and initialized before the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you would initialize j in the first statement in the for loop (which is empty here) since it is a looping index and is usually only used inside the loop. Also the standard syntax for Java for loops is `for( initialization; termination condition; increment)`, but the language only enforces that there be three statements (with the middle one being a boolean expression) , so you can have three empty statements `for(;;)` which creates an infinite loop or you could put some other statement in there (except for the middle expression where a boolean expression is expected) like `for(System.out.println("I was supposed to initialize here"); false && true; logger.log("Nope."))`. OF course, you shouldn't do that, but it is legal.

Note: Some statements would be illegal if put in place of the third statement as well, like variable declarations, since it is executed at the end of each iteration (see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14) for more on legal for loop syntax)

I like to think of for loops as a shorthand for a common form of the while loop, where you want to loop a number of times:

```
int i= 0;        // Initialization 
while (i< max){  // termination 
  // Do stuff
  i++;             // increment 
}
```

which is helpful for understanding what it does with these statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(initialization; condition; increment)
```

None of them are a must to declare a for loop. You can have a for loop like `for(;;)` if you want. It will compile without any errors.

According to your question j have been already initialized some where. Therefore it is perfectly fine.